# Embeded charts in email body from excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, outlook

I have a worksheet with charts and I’d like to send them in email body. My code works but I’d like to resize charts cause they are too big. 3rd chart is displayed correctly but I don’t see 1st and 2nd charts. They are just blank.

```
 Sub Send_charts()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim ChartName1, ChartName2, ChartName3, Filename As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

ChartName1 = Environ$("temp") & "\Chart1.gif"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Export _
    Filename:=ChartName1, FilterName:="GIF"
ChartName2 = Environ$("temp") & "\Chart2.gif"
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.Export _
    Filename:=ChartName2, FilterName:="GIF"
ChartName3 = Environ$("temp") & "\Chart3.gif"
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart.Export _
    Filename:=ChartName3, FilterName:="GIF"


   On Error Resume Next
   With OutMail
     .Subject = "XX"
    .HtmlBody = .HtmlBody & "<html><body><img src=" & "'" & ChartName1 & " height='200' width='450'><Br><Br><Br/></body></html>"
    .HtmlBody = .HtmlBody & "<html><body><img src=" & "'" & ChartName2 & " height='150' width='250'><Br><Br><Br/></body></html>"
    .HtmlBody = .HtmlBody & "<html><body><img src=" & "'" & ChartName3 & "'><Br><Br><Br/></body></html>"
    .Display
   End With
   On Error GoTo 0

    Kill ChartName1
    Kill ChartName2
    Kill ChartName3
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```